# Facebook JS SDK + C# SDK Logic

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, facebook

I've been playing around with Facebook JavaScript SDK and Facebook SDK for .NET (Web) to try and create a simple `Page tab app` which does the below:

- Show welcome page
- If user likes the page, ask for proper extended permissions and redirect to another page reserved for fans only
- Use the access token from the login to do things on the user behalf.

Anyway, my problem is with the logic of the whole thing, as the user enters the page what should I do after loading the JS SDK? It automatically shows the permissions box so that I could get the extended permissions `user_likes` instead of showing the welcome page.
My other issue is with the access token that is going to be used later in time. Should i store it in session state? if yes, how? What happens if i try to access it and it's expired?

I know this is a general question but please could someone guide me through the best practices to initialize and use the facebook SDK in a .NET WebForms tab app?

Thanks a lot.

(I've read through both docs on Facebook and C# SDK. Great for browsing the API but not much documentations or examples about .NET WebForms)